# is Date to to_date as Time is to to_time (in sql?)

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that for instantiating date we just do
my_date Date; (for example)
and when we insert the date in the table we do

```
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (31, to_date('17/04/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'Air');
```

do we do the same for time? can we do my_time Time; when instantiating?

```
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (31, to_time('12:55:34', 'hh:mm:ss'), 'Air');
```

it gives an error "invalid datatype"

Comment: Looks like Oracle?  There is no separate date and time data types.  DATE type stored date AND the time

Comment: I'm using Oracle

Comment: @OldProgrammer can you show how pls?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? [Datetime datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7690645A-0EE3-46CA-90DE-C96DF5A01F8F) and [Datetime functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C).

Answer (score 0):

There's no such conversion like `TO_TIME()` in Oracle DB, but there are `TO_DATE()` and `TO_TIMESTAMP` in which date portion must exists. The closest data type might be `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` if it's needed that literal to be inserted into that column in the following format

```sql
INSERT INTO Orders(order_date2) VALUES (INTERVAL '0 12:55:34' DAY TO SECOND);
```

where leading **zero**, which might be replaced with an integer value upto **99**, represents the day portion

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a20e8fac545324b2856a1b297d3c94cc)</kbd>